# SQLDB status code 500

Tags: ibm-cloud

I received a FAILED Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001,
message: `Service broker error : {"description"=>"Service Broker provisioned at this url state is not operational 10002"}` message, when trying to create a new SQLDB service instance.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to confirm that there was a brief issue earlier with the *"Free"* plan but it has since been resolved.

I was able to create a service successfully from the CF command line:

```
$ cf create-service sqldb sqldb_free randalstTestSQLDB515
Creating service randalstTestSQLDB515 in org johndoe@myemail.com / 
space dev as johndoe@myemail.com...
OK
```

Try to create the service from the command line using the following syntax:

```
$ cf create-service sqldb sqldb_small mySQLDB
```

where

The first attribute *sqldb* is the **service name**.
The second attribute is the **plan**, either *sqldb_small*, *sqldb_free*, or *sqldb_premium*.
The last attribute *mySQLDB* is the **unique name** that you are giving to this service instance.